# How do you order of operations on Java FX 2 bindings?

Tags: data-binding, javafx-2, jfxtras

EDIT: 
I went back and provided a long explanation of each of the below.... Then I started thinking.  I think my issue was the division element (getUnitDivisionFactor()) was not observable.  I changed this to an observable data type and it all started working.  So rather than delete this "stupid question" I will leave it around.  Perhaps this will help someone else.

I am using JFXtras 2.  There is an "LCD" widget that has a valueProperty binding.  It is a double binding.  I am binding like this... Which is not working...

```
    xLcd.valueProperty().bind(TinygDriver.getInstance().m.getAxisByName("x").getMachinePositionSimple().subtract(TinygDriver.getInstance().m.getAxisByName("x").getOffset()).divide(tg.m.getUnitDivisionFactor()));
```

The problem I really need to do the subtraction first..

> (getMachinePositionSimple - getOffset()) / getUnitDivisionFactor()

However I am a bit stumped on how to do this in a single binding setup.  I think number bindings might be the way to go.  However, not quite sure how to set that up right?

Any help would be great.

Riley

Comment: not working means what? Also what type is `TinygDriver.getInstance().m.getAxisByName("x").getMachinePositionSimple()`

Comment: I tried to play with such expressions, and everything should work right, if you use properties in expressions like substract, divide. I mean, your expression should evaluate what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the input sergey and alexander.  I wrote this question after spending a few hours coding and it was late.  Sorry to be a bother!

Answer (score 0):

The getUnitDivisonFactor() was returning a regular double data type.  I changed this to a SimpleDoubleProperty and everything just started working.. See

> xLcd.valueProperty().bind(TinygDriver.getInstance().m.getAxisByName("x").getMachinePositionSimple().subtract(tg.m.getAxisByName("x").getOffset()).divide(tg.m.gcodeUnitDivision));